# From 3D to 2D-array Basemap plot (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to plot data on a map (basemap) according lon/lat arrays with the following shapes:

```
lon (Ntracks, Npoints)
lat (Ntracks, Npoints)
data(Ntracks, Npoints, Ncycles)
```

The problem is that, with the code I did below, nothing is displayed on the map (and it's terribly slow! even close to out of memory error...). I'm probably using the wrong method. Can I have your help to be able to convert this 3D-data array to a 2D one to use the pcolormesh function ?

```
map = Basemap(projection='mill',lat_ts=10,\
            llcrnrlon= -11.01472, \
            urcrnrlon=  2.769825, \
            llcrnrlat=  43.292, \
            urcrnrlat=  52.10833, \
            resolution='l')

# Zone
lonmin, lonmax = map.lonmin, map.lonmax
latmin, latmax = map.latmin, map.latmax       

# Missing value
misval = 99.999

# Masks on Lon/Lat arrays
lon = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(lon) == True, lon)
lat = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(lat) == True, lat)
lon = np.ma.masked_where(lon <= lonmin, lon)
lon = np.ma.masked_where(lon >= lonmax, lon)   
lat = np.ma.masked_where(lat <= latmin, lat)
lat = np.ma.masked_where(lat >= latmax, lat)

# Dimensions
Ntracks, Npoints, Ncycles = data.shape
'''
#-----------------
# TRACKS LOCATIONS 
# IT WORKS => SEE FIGURE POSTED BELOW
#-----------------
for track in range(Ntracks): 
  x, y = map( *np.meshgrid( lon[track,:], lat[track,:] ))
  y = y.T
  map.plot(x, y, marker= 'o',    \
               markersize=1.5, \
               color='#0B610B',
               markeredgecolor='#0B610B')

'''
#-----------------
# TRACKS DATA 
# => NOT WORKING !!
#-----------------
Data = np.full( (Npoints*Npoints), misval )

for track in range(Ntracks): 
  x, y = map( *np.meshgrid( lon[track,:], lat[track,:] ))
  y = y.T
  for c in range(Ncycles):
    Data[0:Npoints] = data[track,:,c]

    Data = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(Data) == True, Data)
    Data = np.ma.masked_where(Data >= misval, Data)

    Data = Data.reshape( (Npoints, Npoints) )

    # plot Data on the map
    map.pcolormesh(x, y, Data)


parallels = np.arange( latmin, latmax, 2., dtype= 'int')
meridians = np.arange( lonmin, lonmax, 2., dtype= 'int')

map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.5, color='white')
map.drawcountries(linewidth=1.5, color='grey')
map.drawparallels(parallels, labels= [1,0,0,0], color= 'black',   fontsize=16, linewidth=0)
map.drawmeridians(meridians, labels= [0,0,0,1], color= 'black', fontsize= 16, linewidth=0)
map.drawmapboundary(color='k',linewidth=2.0)
map.fillcontinents(color='#cdc5bf')
```

This code generates no error but no data is dispayed on the map...
Here is an example of what the code is returning in output for Ntracks=1 and Ncycles=4 :

```
FILE 0 TRACK 011
CYCLE 1
[[-- 60.779693603515625 60.658145904541016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.779693603515625 60.658145904541016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.779693603515625 60.658145904541016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 ..., 
 [-- 60.779693603515625 60.658145904541016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.779693603515625 60.658145904541016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.779693603515625 60.658145904541016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]]
CYCLE 2
[[-- 60.7838249206543 60.666202545166016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.7838249206543 60.666202545166016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.7838249206543 60.666202545166016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 ..., 
 [-- 60.7838249206543 60.666202545166016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.7838249206543 60.666202545166016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- 60.7838249206543 60.666202545166016 ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]]
CYCLE 3
[[-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]]
CYCLE 4
[[-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [-- -- -- ..., 0.0 0.0 0.0]]
```

I should have something like this (and do a treatment close to 0° lon)
[Tracks locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyaUw.png)

Comment: I am probably missing something... but do you even have enough data to reshape into (600,600)? From this brief description of what you are working with it doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: My original Data array has the following shape: (39,600,841)
and that's probably the missing info, my bad!

I'd like to keep all information in this Data array and be able to plot it on a map with contourf... But I'm missing something too, as I don't know which method to use.

Comment: I have re-edited my first post to show the last code I did.

Comment: to convert the array should be no problem, but unfortunately, I dont understand your code. Is this, what you run? I think with `m` you mean matplotlib.pyplot? You should better post the whole code, so that we can reproduce the problem. Did you use `m.show()`?

PS: Ah, no, I see, basemap is another package, but anyway a minimal working example would help

Comment: yes this is the code I run. "m" stands for the basemap object from matplotlib.pyplot

Answer (score 0):

This map seems to be a very nice tool, thank you for the hint :)

If I get it right, Data should be a 2D-Array containing a value for each x-y-pair?
But you fill only the first Npoints entries of Data, and then you just reshape it -- so you did not write anything in any rows besides the first of your Npoints x Npoints matrix. This is probably not intended, you want to fill the i-th point into the [i, i]-element of the matrix.

So create the matrix with `Data = np.full((Npoints, Npoints), np.nan)` instead of the 1D-matrix with length N*N you were creating.
And then `np.fill_diagonal(Data, data[track, :, c])`

And I'm not sure if you are right there:

> If `latlon` keyword is set to True, x,y are intrepreted as longitude and
>   latitude in degrees. [...]

is this not what you want?

Comment: Thanks. To me, it's seems to be a basic plot with basemap :)
Anyway, you get it right! That's exactly the problem I have, cause the data I want to plot that way do not correspond to (x,y) projections on the map. I'm just re-structuring Data array in a bad way I guess.

Comment: Well... in your `data` there is a color value for every (track, point, cycle), right?
And you want for every (track, cycle) to fill an xy-array with this value for each point and to fill the rest with NaN?

Comment: Well, I have to keep the default value for latlon (which is False) because I have already used the meshgrid function to get coordinates projections x and y (respectively for lon, lat arrays), which are matrices of shape (Npoints, Npoints). x and y here are not interpreted as lon/lat values anymore.

Comment: yes that's it, each track has different lon/lat arrays, tha's why i'm looping over the Ntracks dimension (to plot all tracks in a single map in fact). 

I also have to loop over the Ncycles dimension to keep all information in data array. Finally, I get a 1D-data array of dimension Npoints. I'd like to reshape it to a 2D-array of shape (Npoints, Npoints) to be coherent with x and y shapes.

Comment: ... in fact, reshaping this 1D-data array to be coherent with x and y locations.

Comment: well, I think now, since the x- and y- arrays are filled according to the order of the points, you need to fill the diagonal elements -> I edit the answer

Comment: Hello! I've filled the diagonal elements, as you suggested, but nothing has changed: empty map...!

Comment: I even tried this code:

Data = np.full( (Npoints, Npoints), 50.)
x, y = m( *np.meshgrid( lon[0,:], lat[0,:] ))
y = y.T
m.pcolormesh(x, y, Data)

I should see a red track on the map (according the range of my colorbar), but I can't see nothing...

Comment: I have to keep the "latlon" keyword set to False as I want to plot data on the map according projections coordinates. Thanks for you're help.

Comment: well, strange; a pity, but I have no other guess - I don't understand sufficiently what colormesh does... sorry, and good luck :)